# Ubuntu - DNS not automatically configured. Has to be set manually in /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns, resolv.conf

When I connect to a network (e.g. home or work network), I have to manually enter the nameserver adresses in /etc/resolv.conf every time (I change to a new network). It used to be automatic. Any ideas how to change this back to automatic again ?

Comment: check /etc/dhclient.conf and go to the line starting with request, see if you can find domain-name-servers.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/resolv.conf` should be a symbolic link to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` which is updated automatically by `resolvconf` when the network configuration changes. Your `/etc/resolv.conf` is probably a separate file.

Just check it with:

```
ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
```

Rename or delete this file and make a symbolic link to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`

```
ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Didn't work :-(

Comment: sudo ln -s /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/etc/resolv.conf’: File exists

Comment: Sonntex Syndicate, you need to delete/rename existing `/etc/resolv.conf` file before creating a symolic link with the same filename.

Comment: Or use `ln -fs` ... but I'm really skeptical of doing this manually.

Comment: I tried that - renamed it to resolv.conf.backup   - that also didn't work. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change Default DNS 127.0.0.53 To your NEW DNS (Changes the default DNS automatically on reboot) In Terminal:

```bsh
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo reboot
```